# What if CanExecute has to be a method, and not a property?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, inotifypropertychanged

So I have this View:

```
<StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="Name"/>
        <Button x:Name="SayHello"
                Content="Click Me" />
    </StackPanel>
```

And I have this ViewModel:

```
internal class ShellViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
    {

        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Name);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanSayHello());
            }
        }

        public bool CanSayHello()
        {
            bool isenabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name);
            return isenabled;
        }

        public void SayHello()
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Hello, {0}!", Name));
        }
    }
```

But whenever I enter some value in the textbox, I got this exception:

{"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpressionN' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression'."}

In the commercial app that I'm developing I must have the CanSayHello() member in the VM as a method, not as a property. What should I do?

Comment: I'm using Caliburn.Micro here.

Comment: `NotifyOfPropertyChange` as the name directly indicates that it notifies of a property change. If you are restricted to using `CanSayHello()` as the action guard then there is not much else you can do.

Comment: private getter bool, otherwise you will have roll your own commanding... or go with bindings. Considering that it is encapsulated in a single object and there are no vectors to take advantage of...  that design requirement is silly.

Answer (score 2):

You have that exception because you are calling NotifyOfPropertyChange on CanSayHello and CanSayHello is a method, not a property.

Change to:

```
public bool CanSayHello
{
     get { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name); }
}
```

Comment: "In the commercial app that I'm developing I *must* have the CanSayHello() member in the VM as a method, not as a property."

Comment: I don't believe you can do it as you want, e.g. using as a method. Mapping it into a property with NotifyOfPropertyChange being called everytime Name property is changed, Caliburn will evaluate if SayHello button can be enabled or disabled based on CanSayHello bool result. Since SayHello is a button without any parameter, Caliburn.Micro has no way to know when to call CanSayHello method. Why can't you have it as a property?

Answer (score -2):

You should use commands to bind actions to UI items. There is an implementation of `ICommand` called `RelayCommand` which is typically used in most WPF projects. It allows you to use method, property or predicate.

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Caliburn has its own Command implementations, to save coding boilerplate, called Actions, that should be used instead. OP's question use it to bind function and button's click event.

Comment: while it is constructive to a MVVM stand point misses the entire point of the OP question with regard to Caliburn.Micro framework.